# More Decimal Places In Python

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, decimal

Here is my python code:

```
import math

import decimal as dec

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = 3e8

wave = np.array([253.6e-9,283e-9,303.9e-9,330.2e-9,366.3e-9,435.8e-9])

freq = c/wave

potent = np.array([2.6,2.11,1.81,1.47,1.10,0.57])



m,b = np.polyfit(freq,potent,1)
print m,b

e = 1.6e-19

planck = m*e

print planck

plt.plot(freq,potent,'r.')

x = np.linspace(0,10,11)

y = m*x + b

plt.plot(x,y,'b-')
```

To be specific, I am having trouble at the line containing y = m*x + b. The output of said line is

```
array([-2.27198136, -2.27198136, -2.27198136, -2.27198136, -2.27198136,
       -2.27198136, -2.27198136, -2.27198136, -2.27198136, -2.27198136,
       -2.27198136])
```

This result is due to the fact that the magnitude of slope 'm' is rather small, and the magnitude of 'b' is rather large. So, how might I overcome this obstacle?

Also, if I write plt.plot(freq,potent,'r.') and plt.plot(x,y,'b-'), will it overlay the plots?

Comment: I'm not sure the question about overlaying the plots makes any sense. The numbers are many many orders of magnitude different from each other, so how could they conceivably be plotted together? Similarly, if your `y` values are so close in value that their difference is at risk of being lost to floating point rounding, how do you expect to see anything but a flat line when you plot them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is called "Loss of significance" or "cancellation" It is rather a  mathematical problem than a computer science one.

What you need to do is to change your algorithm so that cancellation does not occur any more. How to do this for simple cases is described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

But the change of the algorithm is not simple in some cases and may be impossible at all. If you do your calculation with more digits you do not really solve your problem. You rather postpone it. Once you change your numbers you might end up with the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

To display more decimal points add this to the end of your code:

```
print('%.60f' % value_x)
```

".60" indicates 60 decimal places to be displayed and "value_x" represents whatever value you want displayed.

I use this when I need to output the P-value as a real decimal number in addition to the default output which is in scientific notation.

Example:

```
In [1]: pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df['horsepower'], df['price'])
In [2]: print("The Pearson Correlation Coefficient is", pearson_coef, " with a P-value of P = ", p_value, "or ")
In [3]: print('%.50f' % p_value)
Out [4]: The Pearson Correlation Coefficient is 0.8095745670036559  with a P-value of P = 6.369057428260101e-48 or 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000637
```